# VBA: VLookup between two workbooks

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I am wondering if someone can help me out. I created a Userform with 3 comboboxes. Combobox 1 and 2 list all open workbooks. Combobox 3 lists the worksheets from Combobox 2. I now want to run a Vlookup. The lookup values are the values (in this case product codes) in each cell beginning at D9 to the last cell with a value in Column D of the first Worksheet of Combobox2's. The lookup range will be ("A5:S###"[number of rows varies depending on the file]"). 
The Vlookup formula should be in the Column I of the first Worksheet of Combobox2's value starting at "I9" looping through each cell in I9 until all the Codes in D9 are looked up. 
I keep getting error the major one being “Runtime-error '9'”: Subscript out of range. Here is my code.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CancelButton_Click()
    Stopped = True
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Dim ScheduleA As Workbook
Dim Termset As Worksheet
Set ScheduleA = Workbooks(Me.ComboBox1.Value)
  With Me.ComboBox3
  For Each Termset In ScheduleA.Worksheets
            .AddItem Termset.Name
    Next Termset
    End With
End Sub


Private Sub FillACDButton_Click()
    Dim ACDRebateInfo As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim NewRebate As Single
    Dim NewRebateType As String
    Dim LookUp_Range As Range
    Dim ActionCode As String
    Dim ACD_NewRebate As Range
    Dim ACD_NewRebateType As Range
    Dim ACD_ActionCode As Range
    Dim SCC As Range
    Dim Cell As Range
    Set ACDRebateInfo = Workbooks(Me.ComboBox2.Value).Worksheets(1)
    Set ACD_NewRebate = ACDRebateInfo.Range("I9:I500")
    Set ACD_NewRebateType = ACDRebateInfo.Range("J9:J500")
    Set ACD_ActionCode = ACDRebateInfo.Range("B9:B500")
    Set LookUp_Range = Worksheets(Me.ComboBox3.Value).Range("A5:S400")
    Set SCC = ACDRebateInfo.Range("D9:D230")
    With ACDRebateInfo
    For Each Cell In ACD_ActionCode
    ActionCode = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(SCC, LookUp_Range, 17, False)
    Next Cell
    End With
    Unload Me
End Sub



Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim wkb As Workbook
        For Each wkb In Application.Workbooks
            Me.ComboBox1.AddItem wkb.Name
            Me.ComboBox2.AddItem wkb.Name
    Next wkb
End Sub
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the Userform is in a separate workbook from the files I want to run the VLookup on

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is your issue but this piece of code does not make sense:

```
For Each Cell In ACD_ActionCode
    ActionCode = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(SCC, LookUp_Range, 17, False)
Next Cell
```

You are looping through the Action Codes but not using the `Cell` variable

Comment: AnalystCave.com Thank you very much for responding. Do you understand what I am trying to do? What do you mean by I am looping through Action Codes but no using the Cell Variable. Essentially the Workbook from Combobox 2 is an upload template generated by the contract management system I am using to allow changes (price, rebates) to be made to the items. So I am trying to pull all the relevant data (Action Codes, Rebate Values, Rebate Type) into the template from the worksheet which is the Combobox3 value/selection.